# Sorting Specific sheets in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have written a code which will sort all my sheets to ascending and descending order. Now please suggest how should I modify the code so that it sorts only few specific sheets which I have selected.
Eg If I have selected Sheet 2, Sheet 5 and Sheet 7 out of the Total 10 sheets then it should sort only these 3 sheets in the ascending and descending order.

```
Sub Sort_Active_Book()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim iAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
'
' Prompt the user as which direction they wish to
' sort the worksheets.
'
   iAnswer = MsgBox("Sort Sheets in Ascending Order?" & Chr(10) _
     & "Clicking No will sort in Descending Order", _
     vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Sort Worksheets")
   For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
      For j = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
'
' If the answer is Yes, then sort in ascending order.
'
         If iAnswer = vbYes Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) > UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
'
' If the answer is No, then sort in descending order.
'
         ElseIf iAnswer = vbNo Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) < UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
         End If
      Next j
   Next i
End Sub
```

I have also created a Userform for the above functionality, please find below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim u As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long

If Me.OptionButton1 = True Then
' Prompt the user as which direction they wish to
' sort the worksheets.
   For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
   For j = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
'
' sort in ascending order.
'
         If Me.OptionButton3 = True Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) > UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
'
' sort in descending order.
'
         ElseIf Me.OptionButton4 = True Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) < UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
         End If
      Next j
   Next i


ElseIf Me.OptionButton2 = True Then

For i = 1 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount
For j = 1 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
   If Me.ListBox1.Selected(j) = True Then
' sort in ascending order.
         If Me.OptionButton3 = True Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) > UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
 ' sort in descending order.
         ElseIf Me.OptionButton4 = True Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) < UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
         End If
        End If
      Next
   Next
End If


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Sh As Variant
'for each loop the add visible sheets
For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If Sh.Visible = True Then
'add sheets to the listbox

Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sh.Name
End If
Next Sh

Me.OptionButton1 = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way in regards to your code would be to check if the sheet is selected while running your loop through all sheets.

Comment: How do you select your sheets? By clicking or you want to enter the information somewhere?

Comment: I have a userform so in the listbox I select the sheet

Comment: You could use the listitem[i]  property. if Selected, go on, if not, do nothing.

Comment: here Optionbutton1 is to select all sheets and Optionbutton2 is to use only selected sheets,

Comment: Optionbutton2 is ascending and optionbutton4 is descending. In my code when Optionbutton1 is true everything is working that is it is sorting all the sheets based on the Optionbutton3 (Ascending) OR Optionbutton4(Descending) order.

Comment: But the thing which is not working is Optionbutton2 which is for selected sheets in the listbox1

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like this. I have not tested it though:

```
    Dim ss()
    counter = 1
    For Each x In ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets
        ReDim ss(1 To counter)
        ss(counter) = x.Name
        counter = counter + 1
    Next



    for i = 1 to ubound(ss)
        for j = 1 to ubound(ss) - 1

        ...
        ...
        ...

        next j 
    next i
```

In your code instead of Sheets(j).Name write ss(j) and instead on Sheets(j) write TishWorkbook.Sheets(ss(j))

Comment: how should I link it with me.listbox1